# MySQL - how to retrieve the last recorded values grouped by one of the fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `node_weather` that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key |                    |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+--------------------+
| W_id               | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | ement              |
| temperature        | int(10)      | YES  |     |                    |
| humidity           | int(10)      | YES  |     |                    |
| wind_direction     | int(10)      | YES  |     |                    |
| wind_speed         | int(10)      | YES  |     |                    |
| wet_temperature    | int(10)      | YES  |     |                    |
| P_id               | mediumint(9) | YES  | MUL |                    |
| time               | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  |
| level_current      | int(10)      | YES  |     |
```

In this table, I am recording the data from 4 different weather stations, defined by P_id field (=> P_id can be of values 1, 2, 3 or 4). The data is continuosly filling the table, coming from all the stations.

How to create a query to get the last recorded row for each of the weather stations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    node_weather
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        tblInner.P_id,
        MAX(tblInner.time) AS maxTime
    FROM
        node_weather as tblInner
    GROUP BY
        tblInner.P_id
) AS tblMax 
    ON tblMax.maxTime = node_weather.time 
    AND tblMax.P_id = node_weather.P_id
```

this will get the latest combination with max `time` and `P_id`

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking for quite a time, but wanted to handle it just with simple using GROUP BY / ORDER BY without using subqueries (thought it would have to work like that). As I see, subquery was needed.

Comment: one question - when i execute a subquery first separately, I will get a strange result - strange in a way, that the time queried does not respond to the other rows in the resultset corresponding to that time - why is it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. It is faster than sub query..

```
select nw1.* from node_weather nw1
LEFT JOIN node_weather nw2 on nw2.P_id = nw1.P_id and nw2.time>nw1.time
where nw2.W_ID is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM node_weather GROUP BY P_id ORDER BY time DESC`

That should do the trick

Comment: not really, it will just order the final resultset by time descending, but the grouping will not be done according to the time.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your question then, you wanted the last records from each weather station (P_id)? that's why i made a GROUP BY, and then to make sure we get the latest record, i ordered it by time.

The code is untested though, but it should work.

Comment: I have tested it and it does not give me what I want. The point is that when you are doing ordering by time, you are already working with the grouped resultsets. What I need is to first order the whole resultset by time desc, find in it the latest records for each weather station and give and return it.

Comment: yeah, i just realized that, i think one of the other answers might work better. Worth a shot though :)